# Vertical Text in dijit TabContainer Tabs

Tags: dojo, tabcontainer

dijit/layout/TabContainer may have the tab buttons/texts displayed on top, right, bottom and left. I'd like to get tabs on the right (using tabPosition: "right-h"), but even if the tabs are on the right, the texts are still displayed horizontally. "right-h" sounds as if there were plans for a "right-v", to have texts displayed vertically, too, but this seems to be not implemented yet.

How can I achieve vertical display of the tab texts in one of the TabContainers in use in my page (others shall have tabs on top with horizontally rendered texts).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way I can imagine is to split the title of the tabs accros multiple lines.

Like this:

```js
require([
    "dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/query",
    "dijit/layout/TabContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(attr, query, TabContainer, ContentPane){

    query(".tc1cp").forEach(function(n){
        new ContentPane({
            // just pass a title: attribute, this, we're stealing from the node
            title: attr.get(n, "title").split('').join('<br />')
        }, n);
    });
    var tc = new TabContainer({
        style: attr.get("tc1-prog", "style"),
        tabPosition: 'left-h'
    }, "tc1-prog");
    tc.startup();
});
```

```css
.tabLabel {
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">

<div class="tundra">
  <div id="tc1-prog" style="width: 400px; height: 500px;">
    <div class="tc1cp" title="My first tab">
      Lorem ipsum and all around...
    </div>
    <div class="tc1cp" title="My second tab">
      Lorem ipsum and all around - second...
    </div>
    <div class="tc1cp" title="My last tab">
      Lorem ipsum and all around - last...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or by changing the `writing-mode`:

```js
require([
    "dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/query",
    "dijit/layout/TabContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(attr, query, TabContainer, ContentPane){

    query(".tc1cp").forEach(function(n){
        new ContentPane({
            // just pass a title: attribute, this, we're stealing from the node
            title: attr.get(n, "title")
        }, n);
    });
    var tc = new TabContainer({
        style: attr.get("tc1-prog", "style"),
        tabPosition: 'left-h'
    }, "tc1-prog");
    tc.startup();
});
```

```css
.tabLabel {
    writing-mode: tb-rl; /*Note: correct value is vertical-lr but IE10 does not support it*/
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">

<div class="tundra">
  <div id="tc1-prog" style="width: 400px; height: 500px;">
    <div class="tc1cp" title="My first tab">
      Lorem ipsum and all around...
    </div>
    <div class="tc1cp" title="My second tab">
      Lorem ipsum and all around - second...
    </div>
    <div class="tc1cp" title="My last tab">
      Lorem ipsum and all around - last...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```